# Data e Hora automatica

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação no Android e gostaria de saber se alguém sabe de uma aplicação com o código aberto ou saiba do código que verifica se a opção de Data e Hora automática(fornecida pela rede) esta ativada no aparelho.

obrigado

Comment: Você está utilizando qual versão do API?

Answer (score 1):

Uso a 18, mas ja fica a dica, achei esses códigos

API 17 para cima

```
android.provider.Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0);
```

API 16 para baixo

```
android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para isso, utiliza se a propriedade [AUTO_TIME](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#AUTO_TIME) .

Segue um exemplo de implementação:

```
   int type =0;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
           type =  Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0);
        }else{
           type =  Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, 0);
        }
```

Se seu retorno for `1`, então a opção está habilitada! Senão retorna `0`.